# Security Camera Data Usage

Tags: webcam, internet

So I have set up a webcam with https://kerberos.io/, on my Rpi due to some recent vandalism and opened up the appropriate ports to view my camera while away from home.

I know there are other things that affect the bandwidth usage such as amounts of activity and resolution and a few other things.

So my question is because I have limited bandwidth usage every month, I want to make sure that data is only being uploaded to the internet when there is an active request by the client?

Is this correct or do I need to rethink having it available online?

Let me know please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would only be using bandwidth if a client was receiving a stream. If you don't want to use bandwidth don't have a client downloading. It should be just sitting there waiting otherwise.

Comment: This is what I kind of what I thought. But I am by no means an expert.